# Rails: how to exclude one item from an "each" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

I'm using the Enki blogging gem as a type of content management system. It allows you to create posts and pages.  It automatically generates two pages (Home and Archives).  I've also created two other example pages, Services and Products, and will create many more. Therefore, when I want to list all the pages  on the home page, I do this

```
  <% page_links_for_navigation.each do |link| -%>
    <li><%= link_to(link.name, link.url) %></li>
  <% end -%>


Home
Archives
Services
Products
```

I may want to create more pages in the future, so it's better to loop over all the pages like this rather than hardcode the url for each page.

But how would I change that code if I wanted to exclude one of those pages (i.e. archives). Enki automatically generates that page and doesn't give me an option to delete it. Moreever, I don't want to delete Archives, because I want to use it where I post link to blog posts.

So, in short, how would I exclude one particular page from this code

```
  <% page_links_for_navigation.each do |link| -%>
    <li><%= link_to(link.name, link.url) %></li>
  <% end -%>
```

The url for Archives is  localhost:3000/archives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  <% page_links_for_navigation.each do |link| -%>
    <%  if link.name != 'Archives' %>    
      <li><%= link_to(link.name, link.url) %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end -%>
```

or use `page_links_for_navigation.reject {|page| page.name == 'Archives'}.each`

**Edit:**

to add more pages do `!['Archives', 'Home'].include? link.name` or just add the ones you want to include and remove `!`

read

http://www.humblelittlerubybook.com/

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/

Comment: Thanks, these work, but I'm running into trouble if I'm trying to exclude a second page, for example, 'Home" (as well as archives). For example, I did <% if link.name != 'Archives' || 'Home' %>  or, for reject, {|page| page.name == 'Archives', 'Home'} Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for `page_links_for_navigation.reject {|page| page.name == 'Archives'}.each`

Answer (score 11):

another way

```
<% page_links_for_navigation.each do |link| -%>
   <% next if link.name == 'Archives' %>
   <li><%= link_to(link.name, link.url) %></li>
<% end -%>
```